# iMacro - Firefox - OnDownload not working?

Tags: imacros

I'm using the last version of iMacro and of Firefox.
I'm trying to run it so it downloads a .csv into a specific folder on a different drive that's on the network which it does have access to, the machine that is.

However, every time I see to download it, it does it in the default folder.
Now I did change the download folder but, since I need iMacro to also rename it it just won't cut it exactly.

Here's the code. Now I know I inserted a comment in there, I was playing around to make it work.

Thank you.

```
VERSION BUILD=8890130 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=WEBSITE
FRAME F=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:username CONTENT=USERNAME
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT=PASSWORD
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:LOG<SP>IN
URL GOTO=WEBSITE
WAIT SECONDS=15
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:ext-gen1194
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Today
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:button-1030-btnInnerEl
WAIT SECONDS=10
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd}}.csv WAIT=YES
'ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER="\\\\DifferentServer\\path\\path\\path\\path\\path\\" FILE=+{{!NOW:yyyymmdd}}.csv WAIT=YES
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:button-1055-btnIconEl
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSE
```